# Setting BOT properties in AIML

Tags: chat, aiml

In AIML I have seen various files where the Bot properties is being used. For example :

```
<bot name="name" />
```

Here, the bot name is being used, but I am not able to find the place where to set this property, i.e. where should I define the name.

On searching I found that its stored in the .properties ([link](https://pandorabots.github.io/aiml/bot/)) file, but I cannot find the file anywhere.

There is also a github repsitory which has many files and used the `bot properties`, but here also no .properties file : [Repo Link](https://github.com/datenhahn/python-aiml-chatbot)

So, where should I store the .properties file and if not then how should I add the bot properties in AIML.

Comment: did you find anything. i need to set bot properties.

Answer (score 0):

As the  [AIML 2.0 working draft](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1wNT25hJRyupcG51aO89UcQEiG-HkXRXusukADpFnDs4/pub) said:

> The AIML standard does not specify where or how the properties, sets, maps,
>   substitutions and predicates are defined. This is an implementation detail
>   left up to the interpreter designer.

As an example, I am working with [program-ab](https://code.google.com/archive/p/program-ab/) which is a Java implementation of the AIML interpreter.

The properties info of a bot is placed in a file named 
`config/properties.txt`.

The format is like:

```
name: Alice
age: 22
gender: female
```

You can find more info about the program-ab configurations at [Configuration.wiki](https://code.google.com/archive/p/program-ab/wikis/Configuration.wiki).

If you are working with other kinds of implementation such as Python or whatever, the properties file path and its format may be found inside the wiki or docs.

Comment: I'm not sure why Shi's answer was downvoted. Here is more recent documentation that reiterates the point about setting those immutable bot properties being a responsibility of the interpreter, not the ML, even unto no tag available to achieve that:  http://www.aiml.foundation/doc.html